# extract dummy data through web scraping and php dom

Tags: web, screen-scraping, element, selector, simple-html-dom

i want to extract dummy data from the link given below

http://www.apsc.utoronto.ca/Calendars/2012-2013/Course_Descriptions.html#Course1

I've been able to get the course code and course title, but i'm not able to retrieve the course description which if you notice in the source, is wrapped in a `<p>` outside the table.
Any ideas how i can select that p? Been trying a few selectors but i'm not able to select it.

I'm using [Parse Web Pages with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (David Walsh still suggesting it on June 15, 2011)](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications) for selecting and extracting the information.

Answer (score 0):

relative to the table it would be:

```
$xpath->query('./following-sibling::p[1]', $table)->item(0)->nodeValue
```